# hello every one please tell me why this code is not give any response

Tags: javascript

Check the code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function operation(thevalue)
{
    var result;
    var one=document.forms["myform1"]["one"];
    var two=document.forms["myform1"]["two"];
    document.write(one);
    var x=document.getElementById(thevalue).value;

    if(x == "add")
    {
        result=one+two;
        alert ("Answer is : "+result);
    }

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform1">
Enter 1st no :<input type="text" name="one"  /><br/>
Enter 2nd no :<input type="text" name="two"  /><br/>
<input type="radio" id="add" name="operation" value="add" onclick="operation(this.value)" />Add
<input type="radio" id="sub" name="operation" value="sub" onclick="operation(this.value)" />Sub
<input type="radio" id="mul" name="operation" value="mul" onclick="operation(this.value)" />Mul
<input type="radio" id="div" name="operation" value="div" onclick="operation(this.value)" />Div

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please take the time to learn [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: var one and two should be values of those input controls

Answer (score 2):

Your function and the input name had the same name
and you need to extract the get values from the inputs ( and parse them as an number)

http://jsfiddle.net/VfnYB/1/

```
<form name="myform1">
Enter 1st no :<input type="text" name="one"  /><br/>
Enter 2nd no :<input type="text" name="two"  /><br/>
<input type="radio" id="add" name="operation" value="add" onclick="op(this.value)" />Add
<input type="radio" id="sub" name="operation" value="sub" onclick="op(this.value)" />Sub
<input type="radio" id="mul" name="operation" value="mul" onclick="op(this.value)" />Mul
<input type="radio" id="div" name="operation" value="div" onclick="op(this.value)" />Div

</form>



window.op=function(val)
{
    var result;
    var one=parseInt(document.forms["myform1"]["one"].value);
    var two=parseInt(document.forms["myform1"]["two"].value);

    if(val == "add")
    {
        result=one+two;
        alert ("Answer is : "+result);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

change operation to another name which is causing a conflict..

Comment: operation is not a keyword, issue is that the html element (radio buttons) and the function have the same name i.e. operation which is causing a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

1) Change operation to another name since you have named you radio button as "operation"

```
<input type="radio" id="add" name="operation" value="add" onclick="operation(this.value)" />Add
```

2)In your code the ***.value*** part is missing without which you will get only the element and not its value.

```
 var one=document.forms["myform1"]["one"].value;
 var two=document.forms["myform1"]["two"].value;
```